# How to hit Google Place API without CORS issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api

I am trying to get set of Resturents list nearby User Location. I tried it using below code:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  // url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.6639,-83.5552&radius='+config.radius+'&type='+config.type+'=&key= AIzaSyBwJsemNhTY8_HZDc3wAfhUrY0xrLm6EWY'
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+position.longitude+','+position.latitude+'&radius='+config.radius+'&type='+config.type+'=&key= AIzaSyBwJsemNhTY8_HZDc3wAfhUrY0xrLm6EWY'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  Auth.setplaces(PlaceObject);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  return response;
})
```

**Getting Error:** No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

**How can i fix above issue?**

Comment: Try setting dataType: jsonp after url

Comment: I tried making it jsop doesn't solve the problem.